# interview question: correlation of binomial distributions with random $p$

Tags: probability

I happened to an interview question:

> Toss a coin, if the probability of head, $p$ is random. What's the correlation between the number of heads for 100 tossing, $X_{100}$ and the first 10 tossing, $X_10?$

the non-random $p$ version is very easy which has been answered here:

[How to calculate the correlation between the number of heads of 100 toss of coin and the number of heads of the first 10 toss of those 100 tosses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960623/how-to-calculate-the-correlation-between-the-number-of-heads-of-100-toss-of-coin)

We know that when $p$ is known (conditional on $p$),
$$X_{10}|p\sim binomial(10,p),$$
we have
$$Covariance(X_{10}|p,X_{100}|p) = Variance(X_{10}|p) = 10*p(1-p).$$

Then how to calculate the random $p?$ Maybe let's assume $p\sim Uniform(0,1).$ I just want to see the process of calculation.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Thomas sorry, I can only deal with the known $p$ case, pls see my update. And then don't know how to deal with random $p.$

Comment: Why do you think the accepted answer link does not apply ? It looks that the result is independent on the distribution of Y1

Comment: @Thomas I get it, thanks.

Comment: DrHab's answer only applies to binomial distributions.  Here the conditional distribution is binomial for a given $p$, but the unconditional distribution will not be. @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Law of Total Variance to find the unconditional variance.

Let $X_{n}$ be the count for heads among the first $n$ tosses.  $X_{n}\mid p\sim \mathcal{Bin}(n,p)$, and assuming $p\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$...

$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(X_n) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X_n\mid p))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(X_n\mid p))\\&=\mathsf E(np(1-p))+\mathsf{Var}(np)\\&=n\mathsf E(p)(1-\mathsf E(p))+(n^2-n)\mathsf {Var}(p)\\&=\tfrac {2n+n^2}{12}\end{align}$$

Then use that to find the correlation.